# how to convert imageView.image to TiBlob object?

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, photo-gallery

I am trying to save picture in photo gallery
here is my code

```
var views = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    var img = Ti.UI.createImageView({
        image : '/images/' + i + '.jpg'
    });
    views.push(img);
}
scrollableView.setViews(views);
```

and at save button

```
Ti.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(views[scrollableView.currentPage].image, {
    success : function() {
        alert('success');
    },
    error : function(e) {
        alert(e.error);
    }
});
```

it gives error as

```
invalid media type: Exepcted either TiBlob or TiFile, was: String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,just replace

```
views[scrollableView.currentPage].image
```

with

```
views[scrollableView.currentPage].toBlob();
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the lacking of more specific codes, I can just give you some advices after reading your code.

- Like what you written as `var views = []`, and you add objects in `views`. I think you should define the `Type` for `views`. Like `var views = [UIView]()` or `var views = [CustomView]()`
- `var img = Ti.UI.createImageView`, the `img` is the `object` you gonna add to the `views`, I think the `Type` of `views` can be inferred from the Class,`TI`.
- `image : '/images/' + i + '.jpg'`, you should guarantee the name of `JPG Picture`is correct. For example, are you sure `images1.jpg` is the correct name, not the `image1.jpg`?
- `views.push(img)`, I guess the `push` is the custom function in the `Ti`. Because we always use `append` to add the object to an `Array`.
- For the last, your error mentioned about `TiBlob` and `TiFile` which you did not show in your code for question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace `views.push(img);` with `views.push(img.toBlob());`. This should guarantee that you provide a blob object. Nevertheless the image itself must be correct (doublecheck the name etc.).